# Oracle DBMS_RANDOM algorithm?

Tags: random-number-generator

Oracle DBMS offer builtin random number generator (pseudo to be accurate). DBMS_RANDOM is one of the available packages, it is however considered as insecure for cryptography.
Do we happen to know the algorithm used by this method ?

Comment: What research have you done?  There's lots written in textbooks and on the Internet (and on this site) about the criteria for a PRNG to be fit for cryptography.  Also, please, one question per question; you've crammed two different questions into one post.

Comment: My research on the DBMS_RANDOM didn't yield any information about the used algorithm. If I've missed something, I'd be grateful if you can point it out.

Comment: I removed the second part as indeed there is enough information. The first question concerns an Oracle product, so there is no source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search shows the source code is available in the file `dbmsrand.sql`, which says:

```
-- Delayed Fibonacci, pilfered from Knuth volume 2
```